# Display a header for each grouping of items in a repeater?

Tags: c#, sitecore, repeater

I have an product order review page that displays a list of whatever the user has entered. What is needed is the name of the location that each product or product grouping belongs to (i.e. If the user selected 3 products from under the "Desks" listing, those three products should appear under the header "Desks" on the order review page. If the user purchased 5 items from under the "Lobbies" listing, then those 5 products should appear under the header "Lobbies" on the order review page).

Currently, I can get the correct header text, but the text repeats itself with each item (i.e. The header "Desks" appears above each of the 3 items ordered under the "Desks" listing). I would like it to appear only once per item/grouping of items but I am not sure how to do it.

I am using a repeater to display the order information to the user, and everything else is working the way I want it. It's just this little bit I'm confused about. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Here is the designer code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="orderRepeater" runat="server" >
    <itemtemplate>
        <h3 class="locationName"><%# Eval("LocationName") %></h3>
        <div class="headerRow">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="thumb"><p></p></div>
                <div class="headerField name"><p class="hField">Product</p></div>
                <div class="headerField sku"><p class="hField">GOJO SKU</p></div>
                <div class="headerField size"><p class="hField">Size</p></div>
                <div class="headerField case"><p class="hField">Case Pack</p></div>
                <div class="headerField qty"><p class="hField">Quantity</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="thumb"><%# Eval("Thumbnail") %></div>
                <div class="field name"><p class="pField"> <%#Eval("ProductName") %> </p></div>
                <div class="field sku"><p class="pField"> <%#Eval("Sku") %></p></div>
                <div class="field size"><p class="pField"> <%#Eval("Size") %></p></div>
                <div class="field case"><p class="pField"><%#Eval("CasePack") %></p></div>
                <div class="field qty"><p class="pField"><%#Eval("Qty") %></p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Label lbl = (Label)FindControl("orderLbl");
    Item CurrentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
    Item HomeItem = ScHelper.FindAncestor(CurrentItem, "gojoMarket");

    if (Session["orderComplete"] != null && Session["orderComplete"] != "")
    {

        if (HomeItem != null)
        {
            Item ProductGroup = HomeItem.Axes.SelectSingleItem(@"child::*[@@templatename='gojoMarketOfficeBuildigProductMap']/*[@@templatename='gojoOrderReview']");

            Database db = Sitecore.Context.Database;
            DataSet dset = new DataSet();


            if (ProductGroup != null)
            {
                string InFromSession = Session["orderComplete"].ToString();

                try
                {
                    DataTable summary = dset.Tables.Add("summary");

                    summary.Columns.Add("LocationName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                    summary.Columns.Add("Thumbnail", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                    summary.Columns.Add("ProductName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                    summary.Columns.Add("Sku", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                    summary.Columns.Add("Size", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                    summary.Columns.Add("CasePack", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                    summary.Columns.Add("Qty", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                    summary.Columns.Add("Location", Type.GetType("System.String"));

                    Label qL = (Label)FindControl("qty");
                    string[] orders = InFromSession.Split(';');
                    foreach (string order in orders)
                    {
                        int total = orders.GetUpperBound(0);
                        if (order != "")
                        { 
                            string[] infos = order.Split(',');

                            string ids = infos.GetValue(0).ToString();

                            string qtys = infos.GetValue(1).ToString();

                            if (ids != "")
                            {
                                Item CatalogueItem = db.Items[ids];
                                DataRow drow = summary.NewRow();

                                Item LocationItem =  ScHelper.FindAncestor(CatalogueItem, "gojoProductLocation");
                                if (LocationItem != null)
                                {
                                    //this returns the header text values that I need
                                    string LocationName = LocationItem.Fields["Header"].ToString();

                                    drow["LocationName"] = LocationName;
                                }
                                    Item orderItem = db.Items[CatalogueItem.Fields["Reference SKU"].Value];
                                    if (orderItem != null)
                                    {
                                        Item marketItem = db.Items[orderItem.Fields["Master Product"].Value];
                                        if (marketItem != null) 
                                        {
                                            Item CPNItem = db.Items[marketItem.Fields["Complete Product Name"].Value];

                                            drow["Thumbnail"] = "";

                                            Sitecore.Data.Fields.XmlField fileField = marketItem.Fields["Thumbnail"];
                                            drow["Thumbnail"] = "<image src=\"" + ScHelper.GetCorrectFilePath(fileField) + "\" border=\"0\" alt=\"\">";

                                            if (CPNItem != null)
                                            {
                                                var name = CPNItem["Complete Name"];
                                                drow["ProductName"] = name;
                                            }

                                            drow["Sku"] = marketItem.Fields["SKU"].Value;
                                            drow["CasePack"] = marketItem.Fields["Case Pack"].Value;
                                            if (marketItem.Fields["Size"] != null)
                                            {
                                                drow["Size"] = marketItem.Fields["Size"].Value;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                drow["Size"] = "N/A";

                                            }

                                            drow["Qty"] = qtys.ToString();
                                            summary.Rows.Add(drow);
                                        }
                                    }



                             }

                        }
                    }
                    orderRepeater.DataSource = dset;
                    orderRepeater.DataMember = "summary";
                    orderRepeater.DataBind();
                }
                catch (Exception x)
                {
                    Response.Write(x.Message.ToString());

                }
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        HyperLink none = (HyperLink)FindControl("link");
        Label msg = (Label)FindControl("msgLbl");
        none.Visible = true;

        msg.Text = "You have not selected any items for purchase. To purchase items, please visit our complete product listing: ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the header in the `<HeaderTemplate>`. So it'd look like:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="orderRepeater" runat="server" >
    <HeaderTemplate><h3><asp:Literal runat="server" id="header" /></h3></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>[your existing code here]</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And in code behind do something like:

```
protected void orderRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
    {
        ((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("header")).Text = "The header" // Whatever you would like this to be;
    }
}
```